# How to return data from one API to another API in node js http method without other third party

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am creating an API which is an in between API for filtering between client app and second API. So when app calls first API it filters and calls second API with the query and second API is returning the value and I am receiving the data in console, but when I try to send it back to the app, it shows an error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I am a beginner so let me know if anywhere sending back response or returning value is wrong.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth')
const users = require('../../config/List');
//const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('config');
const dbUser = config.get("usr");
const dbpassword = config.get('pass');
const dbConnectionString = config.get('conn');
const http = require('http');
router.post('/', auth, async(req, res) => {
  let transfers = {};
  console.log("auth route" + req.email);
  const queryEmail = "?email=" + req.email;
  const options = {
    hostname: 'website',
    path: '/api/auth' + queryEmail,
    method: 'POST',
    port: 2000,
    headers: {
      'authtoken': req.header('authtoken')
    }
  };
  //Sending the request
  http.request(options, (response) => {
    let data = ''
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    // Ending the response 
    response.on('end', () => {
      transfers = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(transfer);
      return transfers;
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err)
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```